# Count the number of distinct value based on a condition for the whole column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm new to VBA and need some help with the following:

In Column E for value "abc", i would like to obtain the number of distinct value in Column J, which is 2 (to be shown in Column BB).

[example in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyIwQ.png)

I've applied the array formula

=SUMPRODUCT((($E$2:$E$226=E2))/COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$226,$E$2:$E$226&"""",$J$2:$J$226,$J$2:$J$226&""""))

in the code, but it only works for row 2 to 226. 
I'll be adding in more data in the future, is there any way to do this such that the whole column would be taken as reference?

```
Sub TransferData()
Dim lr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet3.Cells.ClearContents

With Sheet2.[A1].CurrentRegion
.AutoFilter 42, "Y"
.EntireRow.Copy Sheet3.[A1]
.AutoFilter

End With

lr = Sheet3.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If lr <= 1 Then Exit Sub
Sheet3.Range("BA2:BA" & lr) = "=COUNTIF(HistoricalSVOS!$B:$B, DefectRate!$E:$E)"
Sheet3.Range("BB2").FormulaArray = "=SUMPRODUCT((($E$2:$E$226=E2))/COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$226,$E$2:$E$226&"""",$J$2:$J$226,$J$2:$J$226&""""))"
Sheet3.Range("BB2:BB" & lr).FillDown

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Appreciate all your help!

Regards,

Kw007

Answer (score 2):

replace all the `226` with `" & lr & "`

```
Sheet3.Range("BB2").FormulaArray = "=SUMPRODUCT((($E$2:$E$" & lr & "=E2))/COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$" & lr & ",$E$2:$E$" & lr & "&"""",$J$2:$J$" & lr & ",$J$2:$J$" & lr & "&""""))"
```

Answer (score 0):

By default change the excel row count to "65536".

```
Sheet3.Range("BB2").FormulaArray = "=SUMPRODUCT((($E$2:$E$65536=E2))/COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$65536,$E$2:$E$65536&"""",$J$2:$J$65536,$J$2:$J$65536&""""))"
```